# SUMIFS not matching blank values

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

The SUMIFS formula in my VBA code works for values except when I am trying to find blanks.

Example source dataset:

| Date (column G in original sheet) | Customer (column O in original sheet) | TransactionValue (column E in original sheet) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-26 05:45:00 GMT |  | 100 |
| 2021-02-26 05:45:00 GMT | JohnDoe | 20 |
| 2021-02-26 07:12:18 GMT | JohnDoe | 15 |
| 2021-02-26 07:12:18 GMT |  | 75 |
| 2021-02-26 12:22:55 GMT | JaneDoe | 28 |
| 2021-02-26 12:22:55 GMT | Joe Blogs | 85 |

I am then building something that looks a little like a pivot table, with the desired output being the total for each customer for each timestamp:

| Date |  | JohnDoe | JaneDoe | Joe Blogs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-26 05:45:00 GMT | 100 | 20 |  |  |
| 2021-02-26 07:12:18 GMT | 75 | 15 |  |  |
| 2021-02-26 12:22:55 GMT |  |  | 28 | 85 |

```vb
Dim r as Range
Dim finalcolumn as Long

finalcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

Set r = Cells(2, 2)
With r
    .Formula = "=SUMIFS(Results!$E:$E,Results!$O:$O,Static2!B$1,Results!$G:$G,Static2!$A2)"
    .AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, finalcolumn))
End With
```

This doesn't return anything for the second column, i.e. where Customer is blank. It works for all other customer names.

Comment: For the record, i have tried `=IF(ISBLANK(Cells(1,2),SUMIFS(Results!$E:$E,Results!$O:$O,"""",Results!$G:$G,Static2!$A2),SUMIFS(Results!$E:$E,Results!$O:$O,Static2!B$1,Results!$G:$G,Static2!$A2))"
 but that throws a Run-time (1004) error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.Formula = "=SUMIFS(Results!$E:$E,Results!$O:$O,IF(Static2!B$1="""","""",Static2!B$1),Results!$G:$G,Static2!$A2)"
```